# How to say correctly "My age was smaller?"

Tags: sentence-choice, ielts

I was preparing for IELTS speaking and tried to say that I was younger than my classmates using the phrase "My age was smaller". But it seems unnatural, isn't it? How say it correctly, "My age was [the missing word]"?

Thanks a million!

Comment: You're right. It is unnatural, because you're trying to use a phrase that native English speakers don't use -- nobody (to my knowledge) says "My age was..." anything. It's "I'm younger than..." or "I'm older than..." Only if you want to be silly or pretentious do you say something like, "I have many more years on this earth than she does."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that "My age is smaller than ___" is not standard usage, but "I am younger than ___." is fine.

Comment: We speak of age as _greater_ or _less_ rather than _larger_ or _smaller_, but, as @SoronelHaetir says, it is much more idiomatic to say "I am younger".